# Why doesn't C print to shell until newline?

Tags: c, linux, macos, shell

In C, sometimes my output will not get printed to Terminal until I print the newline character `\n`. For example:

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello, World");
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

The Hello World will not get printed until the next `printf`  (I know this from setting a breakpoint in gdb). Can someone please explain why this happens and how to get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: From TI wiki, but relevant for understanding this: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Tips_for_using_printf#Buffering_modes

Comment: linebuffering (setvbuf(3) or stdbuf(1))

Answer (score 8):

This is done for performance reasons: passing data to console is too expensive (in terms of execution speed) to do it character-by-character. That is why the output is buffered until the newline is printed: characters are collected in an array until it is time to print, at which time the entire string is passed to the console. You can also force output explicitly, like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to `fflush()` you can set the buffering options with [setvbuf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf).